# Multiple feature vectors in weka

Tags: vector, weka

I am working in a Text categorization project using Weka,I have 12 class
I need to find text keywords for each class that distinguish one class from others,
So I am thinking to make feature vector(FV) for each class independently and store 12 (FV)s in separated 12 arff files!

The Question Is  --> How can I combine 12 different Feature vectors in one feature vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on classes overlapping or not, I propose two different approaches instead of joining the feature vectors:

- If classes are not overlapping (that is, no document is in two or
  more classes at the same time), you would rather build a single ARFF
  file and then make use of the `AttributeSelection` filter (`Ranker`
  search, `InfoGainAttributeEval` evaluator suggested) to determine which
  features most discriminate among all the classes.
- If classes are overlapping, you could build twelve one-again-the-rest
  classifiers, each one with its own vocabulary. You could apply
  attribute selection to each independent problem as well, finding the
  features that best discriminate a single class from all of the rest.

Comment: yup I have classes that are overlapped, So can you please clarify more how to apply attribute selection to each independent class?
and what do you mean by "one-gain-the-rest" classifier ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant one-against-the-rest. First create one ARFF file with 12 binary attributes (for each class). This way you can have an instance like `'my text',0,1,1,...` meaning that the text belongs to classes 2 and 3, for example. Then you generate 12 files by using the `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove` to remove the columns you do not need. Then you apply the first option (AttributeSelection and so on) to each file independently. However it is better to use MEKA instead of WEKA in that case. See: http://meka.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Do you mean weka.filters.supervised.attribute.NominalToBinary?

Anyway I found a way but can you tell me if it is true or not?

I have chosen the best 1000 words from each class by applying StringToWordVector for each class independently, after that I make copy and past manually for the attributes in each 12 text file,so I have 12 distinct text files {My new text dataset} then for each text file I make 10 copies of it and store it in folder {So I have 12 class folders with 11 texts}
now I apply StringToWordVector again and I got 100% accuracy!
can this give me good or bad classifier model?

Comment: in other words, can I repeat the text dataset so the accuracy will increase ?

Comment: I am afraid I simply do not understand what you have done :-(

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation ....

I have Windows7 OS and want to use **MEKA GUI** what I did is the following:

 1. downloading meka-release1.5.zip from [http://sourceforge.net/projects/meka/files/meka-1.5.0/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meka/files/meka-1.5.0/)
 
 2. extracting it, and type run.bat in cmd.exe 

But I had the following Error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class .\lib\Jama.jar



Can you help with clear steps how to install and use MEKA EXplorer?